# R HTTP POST with connection

Tags: r, http, stream

I want to write data from R to an HTTP POST API by writing into an R connection because the data may be very large, and we don't want to try to fit it all on disk.  So far as I can tell, [httr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.1) does not provide connection-oriented access to data streams.  [Curl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html#streaming_data) does, but only for fetching data.

I could open the TCP connection manually and write the HTTP headers, but I am hoping for an easier solution.